# Kusto Query from c#

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I want to retrieve data from Kusto DB from c# app can any one help me on this.
I have knowledge on writing the Kusto queries but I need some help on pulling data from Azure Kusto DB hosted in Azure.

I tried the following code but it's not working:

```
var client = Kusto.Data.Net.Client.KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider("https://help.kusto.windows.net/Samples;Fed=true");
var reader = client.ExecuteQuery("MyTable | count");
// Read the first row from reader -- it's 0'th column is the count of records in MyTable
// Don't forget to dispose of reader when done.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could you please elaborate what's not working (what is the error message you're getting) with the code above?

In addition, a full (though simple) example can be found below:

```cs
// This sample illustrates how to query Kusto using the Kusto.Data .NET library.
//
// For the purpose of demonstration, the query being sent retrieves multiple result sets.
//
// The program should execute in an interactive context (so that on first run the user
// will get asked to sign in to Azure AD to access the Kusto service).
class Program
{
    const string Cluster = "https://help.kusto.windows.net";
    const string Database = "Samples";
    static void Main()
    {
        // The query provider is the main interface to use when querying Kusto.
        // It is recommended that the provider be created once for a specific target database,
        // and then be reused many times (potentially across threads) until it is disposed-of.
        var kcsb = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(Cluster, Database)
        .WithAadUserPromptAuthentication();
        using (var queryProvider = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider(kcsb))
        {
            // The query -- Note that for demonstration purposes, we send a query that asks for two different
            // result sets (HowManyRecords and SampleRecords).
            var query = "StormEvents | count | as HowManyRecords; StormEvents | limit 10 | project StartTime, EventType, State | as SampleRecords";
            // It is strongly recommended that each request has its own unique
            // request identifier. This is mandatory for some scenarios (such as cancelling queries)
            // and will make troubleshooting easier in others.
            var clientRequestProperties = new ClientRequestProperties() { ClientRequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
            using (var reader = queryProvider.ExecuteQuery(query, clientRequestProperties))
            {
                // Read HowManyRecords
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var howManyRecords = reader.GetInt64(0);
                    Console.WriteLine($"There are {howManyRecords} records in the table");
                }

                // Move on to the next result set, SampleRecords
                reader.NextResult();
                Console.WriteLine();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Important note: For demonstration purposes we show how to read the data
                    // using the "bare bones" IDataReader interface. In a production environment
                    // one would normally use some ORM library to automatically map the data from
                    // IDataReader into a strongly-typed record type (e.g. Dapper.Net, AutoMapper, etc.)
                    DateTime time = reader.GetDateTime(0);
                    string type = reader.GetString(1);
                    string state = reader.GetString(2);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1,-20}\t{2}", time, type, state);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting the following error on the line  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'KustoConnectionStringBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'WithAadUserPromptAuthentication' and no accessible extension method 'WithAadUserPromptAuthentication' accepting a first argument of type 'KustoConnectionStringBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: which client library version are you using? please include the full name

Comment: It's working i tried it in console app now. Earlier i tried it to add in mvc app.

Comment: How would you do this if you want to connect to multiple clusters/databases?

Comment: the reference to the other cluster, `cluster('othercluster').database('otherdatabase')…` is included in the query's text. your query is being invoked on one cluster (the one you direct to in your code), and it invokes the relevant subquery against the other cluster.

Comment: I get the error  'KustoConnectionStringBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'WithAadUserPromptAuthentication' and no accessible extension method 'WithAadUserPromptAuthentication' accepting a first argument of type 'KustoConnectionStringBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  When I try via dot net core console app with the kusto.data dependency. Should I be using some other dependency for dotnet core?

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299279/kustos-connection-string-problem-in-netcore/58306738#58306738

Comment: It's worth noting that the above example will not for for .Net Core. Only on full framework

Comment: The .NET Core library doesn’t support prompting users for their credentials, so this needs to be provided up front. If you’re using .NET Core and want to perform user authentication, you should be able to do so by setting the following properties on `KustoConnectionStringBuilder`: 1. `UserID`; 2. `Password`; 3. `Federated=true`

Comment: @Yoni is there any other sample or something more in depth than the one you presented in the response? I found the git repo with that example, but I feel it's insufficient. I want to use some ORM but I can't figure out how. Entity Framework doesn't work from what I've tried and I don't know what should I use and where should I start from.